# Update not working in wcf dataservice toolkit

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I am using 'wcf data services toolkit' for CURD operations.
Get/Add/Delete work fine, but Update fails.

In case of Update, I see 'GetOne()' method getting called, but Save() does not get called.

Service Code:

```
public class UserService : ODataService<UserContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}
```

Repository Code:

```
public User GetOne(string id)
{
    return _session.Query<User>().Where(a => a.Id == int.Parse(id)).SingleOrDefault();
}
public void Save(User u)
{
    _session.Store(u);
    _session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Data Context Code:

```
public class UserContext : ODataContext
{
    public IQueryable<User> Users
    {
        get { return base.CreateQuery<User>(); }
    }

    public override object RepositoryFor(string fullTypeName)
    {
        return new UserRepository();
    }
}
```

Model code:

```
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestUpdateUser()
{
    var context = new UserService.UserContext(new Uri("http://localhost:59050/UserService.svc"));
    var user = context.Users.Where(a => a.Id == 385).SingleOrDefault();
    user.UserEmailAddress = "updated@email.com";
    context.UpdateObject(user);
    context.SaveChanges();  

    var context2 = new UserService.UserContext(new Uri("http://localhost:59050/UserService.svc"));
    var updated = context.Users.Where(a => a.Id == 385).SingleOrDefault();
    Assert.AreEqual("updated@email.com", updated.UserEmailAddress)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WCF Dataservice toolkit you will need to implement ODataService for your service.

The ODataService inherits from DataService and provides you with the customisations I'm guessing you are trying to implement.

I would hazard a guess that the problem you have with using ODataService actually lies with the entity you are exposing.

The toolkit is a little picky about how you go about setting up your class.

Make sure you have specified on the User class the following

```
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
```

Where Id is the Key for the entity.

Also any objects/collections should be initialised and if its a foreign property then mark it with the attribute.

```
[ForeignProperty()]
```

I would also setup logging on the service, this will help you debug the issue further

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="10000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="99140000" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Log" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MessageLog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="Log" initializeData="{path to log}" type="{wcf listener}" />
      <add name="MessageLog" initializeData="{path to log}" type="{wcf listener}" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />

  </system.diagnostics>
```

Hope some of this helps

Comment: I updated my question with model code. Also, the log issue was only for root url, remaining service work for for Get/Add/Remove (except update).

Comment: Do you have the Toolkit code included in your project? If so put a break point in the ODataContext file. This file contains a method called SaveChanges, this You will be able to see what operation it is trying to execute. Also Make sure you are using this version of the code http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/Forks/Airslash/SeptemberRelease as this has several fixes in it.

Comment: I am using nuget package. Will try the code and let you know, thanks!